# Specific iteration method on list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a list such as:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What is the best way to iterate through the integers so that I get the return:

```
[1, (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), 2, (2, 3), (2,3,4) 3, (3,4), 4]
```

aka getting every combination without rearranging the numbers.

I tried an idea such as

```
def practice(list1):
    list2 = []
    for i in list1:
        for j in list1:
            list2.append((i, j))
    return list2
```

which returns

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

but not quite what I want.

Sorry if this is simple, still new to/picking up the syntax and functions of this language!

Comment: Do you really want to get a _mixed list_ of integers and tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a generator like this to produce all possible contiguous slices of the list and then make the case distinction for singletons:

```
def practice(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)):  # start index of slice
        for j in range(i, len(list1)):  # end index [-1]
            # differentiate singleton cases
            yield list1[i] if i==j else tuple(list1[i:j+1])

list(practice([1,2,3,4]))
# [1, (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), 2, (2, 3), (2, 3, 4), 3, (3, 4), 4]
```

Comment: it would be superb if using `itertools.islice` to avoid extra lists

Comment: @DanielSanchez True, but overkill for the illustration of this simple logic ;)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `itertools` to get the [combinations (with replacement)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) for the bounds and then return a generator of those. Also, I'd suggest not returning a mixed list, but wrapping the single numbers into one-elemented tuples.

```
import itertools
def practice(lst):
    return (tuple(lst[i:j+1]) 
            for i, j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(lst)), 2))

print(list(practice([1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [(1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (2,), (2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3,), (3, 4), (4,)]
```

Or shorter (thanks to [@schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555372/specific-iteration-method-on-list/47555790?noredirect=1#comment82069533_47555790)), using just `combinations` without replacement but a slightly different `range`. Not sure which of the two is clearer.

```
def practice(lst):
    return (tuple(lst[i:j])  # <-- no +1 here      +1 here --v
            for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(lst)+1), 2))
```

(If this is some sort of programming assignment, this might not be the expected output, but it will likely be much easier to handle in practice.)

Comment: It could be shorter (and maybe cleaner) using `combinations` without replacement, `range(len(lst)+1)` and `lst[i:j]` ;-)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thank, I added this, but to be frank, I still prefer the original version. While `combinations` may be shorter in code, `combinations_with_replacement` directly communicates that `(1,)` should be in the result.

Comment: Well, of course that's a matter of taste. Yet the `(1,)` you mention will always be produced by the slice `[0:1]`, that is two **different** indices which, in turn, is directly implied by no replacement... :D many ways to skin the cat